# Why do we need distributed ledgers? Can we just always send our public key along with the verifiable credentials for validation?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, decentralized-identity

Instead of having decentralized identities, we can just use public keys directly and attach that to verifiable credentials for proof validation?

Comment: I mean, do we really need globally unique identifiers?

Comment: It has been 4 years since this was posted, and I would assert that there are many examples that have proven the need for user-owned identifiers - here's one of note: when Musk took over Twitter he seized the identifiers of some very large accounts, like '@music', which folks had built a decade of followers and community around. If we were using Decentralized Identifiers, this harm would have been totally avoided. There are millions of people who have their centralized IDs taken every year, and I believe the problem will only grow in the years to come.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with using a key directly for identity/creds is that there is no way to roll keys or attach PKI metadata (e.g. routing info) to your ID (which, in this case, would be the public key). Also, if the key you generate is locked to hardware (via an enclave) you would not be able to get a new phone without losing your ID, given use of the ID is bound to possession of the device it was generated on. Furthermore, if you were to attach a high-value credential to a key, and that key was compromised in any way, the ID and your creds would be under the control of the attacker, leaving you no way to sever the credential from the key or recover the provenance of your ID.

Decentralized Identifiers typically use a blockchain to manifest a self-sovereign GUID that can be mapped to keys. This enables you to roll keys, change PKI metadata, and perform recovery against the ID. The ledger acts as a deterministic, decentralized, linear chronology of events, which is uniquely suited for this use case.